# Is there any modern-day replacement for the Ubuntu Mini ISO?

Tags: command-line, system-installation, ubuntu-minimal

I'd like to use Ubuntu on my laptop, but as an experienced user, I would prefer to start off from a command line environment without removing all of the GNOME/GUI stuff. It seems that there [used to be](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) an "Ubuntu Mini" ISO which fits my purposes, but it has been discontinued in favor of a server installer that I have no use for. I would prefer to steer clear of Debian as my school does not officially support it. Do I have any options, or should I go the sad, unsupported Debian path? Many thanks!

Comment: I think the question would be better without disparaging our hardworking friends at Debian. Everybody who uses Ubuntu benefits from their work.

Comment: @user535733 I'm terribly sorry if it seems that I'm saying anything bad about Debian! I love it quite a lot, but my school doesn't want to support it. :(

Comment: You have to use [focal's mini.iso](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/mini.iso) and then upgrade it to the latest release.

Comment: Something worth thinking about here - I traditionally used the mini ISO to cut down on my upfront download. Ubuntu server is the 'same' packages with different defaults , and there's nothing stopping you from building to your needs off that. IIRC it also has a minimal install option?

Comment: As of 23.10, the mini.iso is still available at https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mini-iso/daily-live/current/. A menu will shown asking you which Ubuntu version you would like to install. Personally I don't like this and prefers Arch Linux live iso.

Answer (score 7):

The Ubuntu developers have repeatedly said that the Netinstall (Mini) .iso image was a byproduct of their workflow of the time, not intended for widespread use, that it didn't provide the experience they wanted users to have, and that they wouldn't provide support for it.

(When I've seen Ubuntu Developers at work, I see them mostly use the Desktop and Server installers. Sometimes Ubuntu Base.)

So you were already using an unsupported install method.

The reason that the Netinstall .iso went away is that the installer development workflow changed. There's no longer that byproduct.

If a group of community members wants come together to restore the existence of the Mini.iso, they are completely welcome to take on that work. Ubuntu is open source and community-driven.

The Ubuntu 20.04 mini.iso still exists for a few more years.

Another option: Debian's mini.iso. You can edit the sources and dist-upgrade to use Ubuntu packages instead...which means you will be running Ubuntu.

The Ubuntu installer can be booted using PXE so you can customize your install. Or you can use a preseed file. Or a cloud-init file. There are many custom-install options.

Or you can just use Debian, regardless of what your school says. Ubuntu Developers strive to keep the differences between Ubuntu and Debian to a minimum (carrying patches costs resources!) Server users might not notice much difference.

And, finally, you can use Ubuntu Server. It is *not* bloated. It is fully-supported here, it is 100% real Ubuntu (to make your school happy), it's fast, it's easy to install, it's stable, and it's tested.

Answer (score 6):

You still can use last available [mini.iso of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/mini.iso) and then upgrade installed system to latest version.

Other possible installation method is to use `debootstrap` and then copy this system to somewhere. See [this guide](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/installing-ubuntu-mate-using-debootstrap/23780?u=norbert_x) for Ubuntu MATE as an example.

<sup>Removal of mini.iso was bad idea. Canonical should [follow](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/warty/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/) [their](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) [history](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/) and should respect user habbits. Shame on them! I'm still [disappointed](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/poll-about-possible-netboot-mini-iso-revival-in-future-ubuntu-releases/19457?u=norbert) by this decision.</sup>

Comment: Is it possible to use the base image as the mini iso?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi not really -- Ubuntu base is not bootable and does not include a kernel. Folks who know how to overcome those obstacles don't really need a mini iso.

Comment: @user535733 I see