# How do I install Ubuntu minimal server via USB stick in 2022?

Tags: system-installation

This used to be reasonably straightforward if not easy.

Now, in 2022 I simply can't find any path to installing the latest Ubuntu LTS minimal server via USB stick.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689258/bootable-usb-of-ubuntu-minimal-cd)

Comment: @N0rbert no because that question and answers are years old and things seem to have changed with latest versions.

Comment: Ok, so you can't download latest Ubuntu 20.04 LTS mini.iso from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/mini.iso in 2022???!11

Comment: This isn't documented anywhere and it says it's legacy.  Whilst I appreciate the link thankyou for helping, this leaves a big open question about Ubuntu minimal - no longer documented and listed as legacy is a valid problem to ask about.

Comment: If you check the bottom of https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD you'll not you're asking about a medium that was *never* supported anyway; and is *legacy* as it's no longer produced (it was a byproduct of the creation of ISOs that are no longer produced).   "*Canonical and the Ubuntu project never officially supported the mini.iso ; it was produced as a by-product of building the debian-installer. As the Ubuntu Server image now uses subiquity, the build process that built mini.iso is no longer used, thus why this installation media is now old.*"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as non-reproducible because the Ubuntu Server 20.04 mini.iso downloaded successfully from the link in the accepted answer to [Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://askubuntu.com/q/689258/) and you can still update it because 20.04 is still a supported release.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any modern-day replacement for the Ubuntu Mini ISO?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1390215/is-there-any-modern-day-replacement-for-the-ubuntu-mini-iso)

Answer (score 1):

1. Download Ubuntu Server ISO [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/server)
2. Write Ubuntu Server ISO to USB drive with something like [balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) or [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/)
3. Boot target machine with USB drive. This process can vary depending on your machine and BIOS/UEFI. Most of the time it requires plugging in the USB drive, configuring boot order in BIOS/UEFI to prefer the USB drive, and then booting up the machine.
4. During install process, do not select any additional software (for *minimal* install).

Here is  [Ubuntu's Official Install Guide](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-server#3-boot-from-install-media)

Comment: Not correct, read the comments on the question.